# What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?

Tags: java, linq

What is Java equivalent for LINQ?

Comment: Also for Scala w/ full LINQ API: https://github.com/nicholas22/propelS

Comment: If you wish to make something similar to Linq, but on Android, here's a nice solution: http://www.slideshare.net/droidcon/green-dao http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: @craastad As a .NET guy now mostly stuck in Java world, I feel your pain. You should try Scala though -- first class functions / closures, for comprehensions (not the same as LINQ's query syntax, but useful in many of the same situations), a unified type system, type inference, some convenient workarounds for generic type-erasure ... all running on the JVM, interoperating with Java.  Plus a bunch of other functional goodness like pattern matching, Option type, etc.

Answer (score 843, accepted):

There is nothing like LINQ for Java.

...

**Edit**

Now with Java 8 we are introduced to the [Stream API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), this is a similar kind of thing when dealing with collections, but it is not quite the same as Linq.

If it is an ORM you are looking for, like Entity Framework, then you can try [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/)

:-)

Comment: is there something in the plan?  integrated into the language?  IS ther a JCP number? etc etc.

Comment: Very true, although a big part of what makes LINQ sooo nice is how deeply it is integrated into the language and compiler

Comment: @AgileJon - I don't understand your answer. What's very true? I wasn't being rhetorical with any of my questions.

Comment: Sorry, the 'very true' was meant for 280Z28.  I don't know if there is a JCP for it.  LINQ necessitated several changes to the C# language, given the speed the JCP works at I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: JaQu is the LINQ equivalent for Java. It was developed for H2, but should work for all databases since it uses JDBC. See my answer below.

Comment: [JSR-335](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/proposalDetails?id=335) due in 2012, see my answer below.

Comment: There is nothing like LINQ for Java. java language does not have extension methods. unless java provides native language support for extension methods, real LINQ kind of usability is not possible.

Comment: This is not correct. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879761/is-there-a-java-equivalent-for-linq/10879784

Comment: While this was and still is correct it should be noted that Lambdas were planned for JDK7 before this question was raised and are one of the core components of JDK8. [See my answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq/6790067#6790067).

Comment: EL 3 (AKA JSR-341 http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341) will have its equivalent to LINQ: https://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/CollectionOperations

Comment: LINQ is an specification, not an implementation... Lambda expressions is a part of LINQ. All projects trying to port LINQ to Java are implementations for a concrete scenario (SQL, Objects...) but does not covr the main goal of LINQ: Integrate the Language Query in the code. Due to this, there is no real alternative nor initative, for now, that can be considered as an alternative.

Comment: @nterry A purely subjective and opinionated comment intended to spike an unjust debate.

Comment: @BrettRyan Perhaps, but its objectively true that Java has nothing like it.

Comment: LINQ no, but lambdas yes. In my experience the seasoned C# developers prefer the C# lambdas over LINQ, which implicitly does not make the language infinitely better. The compiler will convert query syntax into method syntax.

Comment: Please update the answer to link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381992/java-equivalent-of-where-clause-in-c-sharp-linq

Comment: Just have a look at this one: http://www.jinq.org/

Answer (score 156):

There is an alternate solution, [Coollection](http://github.com/19WAS85/coollection#readme).

Coolection has not pretend to be the new lambda, however we're surrounded by old legacy Java projects where this lib will help. It's really simple to use and extend, covering only the most used actions of iteration over collections, like that:

```
from(people).where("name", eq("Arthur")).first();
from(people).where("age", lessThan(20)).all();
from(people).where("name", not(contains("Francine"))).all();
```

Comment: String for column name, which means compiler and IDE autocomplete won't help against typoes and refactoring is hard. Any plans to change that?

Comment: Hi, Ekevoo. I think that it will be awsome and I tryed to do that sometime. But at this moment, with Java 8, the Coollection is a deprecated lib. Maybe it's useful to oldest projects... What do you think?

Comment: @WagnerAndrade Last commit is 5-6 years ago. I'm assuming the functionality was largely replaced by Java 8? Also, very cool name :)

Answer (score 148):

[Lambdas are now available](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html) within Java 8 in the form of [JSR-335 - Lambda Expressions for the JavaTM Programming Language](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/proposalDetails?id=335)

**UPDATE**: [JDK8 has now been released](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which contains project lambda. It's worth grabbing a copy of [Java 8 in Action](http://www.manning.com/urma/) currently still MEAP.

Have a read of [Brian Goetz](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/) articles relating to lambdas for a decent understanding of how lambdas are implemented within JDK8 while also gaining an understanding of streams, internal iteration, short-circuiting and constructor references.. Also check out the JSR's above to get further examples.

I've written a blog on some of the advantages of using lambdas in JDK8 called [The Power of the Arrow](http://blog.drunkendev.com/2014/01/the-power-of-arrow.html), also [NetBeans 8](http://netbeans.org) has great support for converting constructs to JDK8 which I've also blogged about [Migrating to JDK 8 with NetBeans](http://blog.drunkendev.com/2014/01/migrating-to-jdk-8-with-netbeans.html).

Comment: Weren't lambdas also scheduled to be in Java 7?  What happened to that?

Comment: Oracle bought Sun (tongue in cheek). Java 7 was taking far too long (5 years) so lambdas missed the short-list, this was rather disappointing to the masses. That being said Oracle does look like it's picking up the ball and I think we're scheduled for Java 8 October next year.

Comment: Note that the [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/sotc3.html) has been updated once again which now covers streams, internal iteration, short-circuiting and constructor references. I advise you all to read the new document.

Comment: Note [the release has been pushed to March 2014](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/), reasons are covered on the [jdk8-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2013-April/002336.html) mailing list and more extensively on [Mark Reinhold’s blog](http://mreinhold.org/blog/secure-the-train).

Comment: Lambda expressions are a little part of LINQ.

Comment: @NeWNeO, if you're referring to the query language in C# then yes, nothing like this is coming to Java, however in my experience most seasoned C# developers prefer lambda syntax over the query language. However if you are referring to LINQ-to-Entities for example then you will find that lambdas in java will enable this and more. There is a lot more coming to Java 8 to enable this, such as [defender methods](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf).

Answer (score 119):

You can select the items in a collection (and much more) in a more readable way by using the lambdaj library

https://code.google.com/archive/p/lambdaj/

It has some advantages over the Quaere library because it doesn't use any magic string, it is completely type safe and in my opinion it offers a more readable DSL.

Comment: This is nice, but it is a far cry from being about to build a query and execute it again sql, xml, collection, etc.

Comment: why might i be getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when using lambdaj select on a custom class in my android project?

Comment: +1 this is really good for those of us who don't care about SQL/XML and only want easier access to collections.

Answer (score 107):

You won't find an equivalent of LINQ unless you use the [javacc](http://java.net/projects/javacc/) to create your own equivalent.

Until that day when someone finds a viable way to do so, there are some good alternatives, such as

- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)
- [JINQ](http://www.jinq.org)
- [JaQue](http://github.com/TrigerSoft/jaque)
- [JaQu](http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html)
- [Linq4j](https://github.com/julianhyde/linq4j)
- [Quaere](https://github.com/codehaus/quaere) (No longer maintained)
- [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com)
- [JSR-341](http://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/CollectionOperations)

Comment: github.com/TrigerSoft/jaque found this way and lets create Expression Trees. Combined with Java 8 Lambdas, any LINQ capacity can be implemented with same effort as in .Net.

Comment: See this answer for a comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989449/parsing-and-translating-java-8-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 50):

**LINQ to Objects** - JAVA 8 has added the Stream API which adds support for functional-style operations on streams of values:

[Package java.util.stream](http://javadocs.techempower.com/jdk18/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

[Java 8 Explained: Applying Lambdas to Java Collections](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/)

**LINQ to SQL/NHibernate/etc. (database querying)** - One option would be to use JINQ which also uses the new JAVA 8 features and was released on Feb 26, 2014 on Github: https://github.com/my2iu/Jinq

> Jinq provides developers an easy and natural way to write database
>   queries in Java. You can treat database data like normal Java objects
>   stored in collections. You can iterate over them and filter them using
>   normal Java commands, and all your code will be automatically
>   translated into optimized database queries. Finally, LINQ-style
>   queries are available for Java!

JINQ project site: http://www.jinq.org/

Comment: Not sure why readers didn't pay attention to your answer even though Stream API is the closest to LINQ!

Comment: Streams API is a bad joke compared to LINQ.

Comment: Sorry man, don't mean to be rude. I was looking for a LINQ equivalent after beating my head off with streams API. i just wanted to say that it's not a real equivalent, that's all.

Comment: @AndreiRînea Are you looking for the LINQ providers (LINQ to XML, LINQ to JSON, LINQ to NHibernate, etc.) equivalent functionality?

Comment: All I needed was a means to group and max on a collection.. I eventually succeeded but with a lot of effort and too much code.

Answer (score 29):

There is a project called [quaere](https://github.com/anoras/Quaere).

It's a Java framework which adds the ability to query collections.

Note: According to the author, the project is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Quaere looks like it provides a bit of what LINQ provides, but the question is for an 'equivalent'

Comment: So it's something *like* LINQ, if not a direct equivalent ? That at least sounds helpful

Comment: @AgileJon: If he really meant equivalent, he wouldn't have asked. He could have typed `from x in xs select x` and found out the answer (no).

Answer (score 17):

There are many LINQ equivalents for Java, see [here](http://source.mysema.com/display/querydsl/Similar+frameworks) for a comparison.

For a typesafe Quaere/LINQ style framework, consider using [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/). Querydsl supports JPA/Hibernate, JDO, SQL and Java Collections.

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, so this answer is biased.

Comment: The "similar frameworks" link is dead. Do you still have an equivalent page?

Comment: When will we get a QueryDSL book?  Or even affordable training options?  Your support link 404s.

Comment: how many people work at queryDsl?

Answer (score 16):

you can use scala, it is similar in syntax and it's actually probably more powerful than linq.

Comment: Esp. Scala's "for comprehensions".

Answer (score 10):

Now that Java 8 supports lambdas, it's possible to create Java APIs that closely resemble LINQ.

[Jinq](http://www.jinq.org) is one of these new LINQ-style libraries for Java.

I am the developer of this library. It is based on five years of research on using bytecode analysis to translate Java to database queries. Similar to how C#'s D-LINQ is a query layer that sits on top of the Entity Framework, Jinq is able to act as a query layer sitting on top of JPA or jOOQ. It has support for aggregation, groups, and subqueries. Even Erik Meijer (the creator of LINQ) has [acknowledged Jinq](https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/448672326603636736).

Answer (score 9):

See [SBQL4J](http://code.google.com/p/sbql4j/). It's type-safe strong query language integrated with Java. Allows to write complicated and multiply nested queries. There is a lot of operators, Java methods can be invoked inside queries so as constructors. Queries are translated to pure Java code (there is no reflection at runtime) so execution is very fast.

EDIT: Well, so far SBQL4J it's the ONLY extension to Java language which gives query capabilities similar to LINQ. There are some interesting project like Quaere and JaQue but they are only API's, not syntax / semantics extension with strong type safety in compile time.

Comment: You may want to mention your role in the project.

Answer (score 9):

As on 2014, I can finally say that LINQ is finally there in java 8.So no need to find an alternative of LINQ anymore.

Comment: Unless you can't code in java 8 (for whatever reason)

Comment: LINQ break the c#-syntax. Java8 syntax can not be broken.

Comment: Citation needed... Are you talking about lambdas? Stream?

Answer (score 8):

Java [LINQ to SQL](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) implementation. Provides full language integration and larger feature set compared to .NET LINQ.

Comment: Can I use JaQue to read/write XML files in the same way we can do with LINQ?

Answer (score 7):

I tried [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) from google. It has a `FluentIterable` which I think is close to LINQ. Also see [FunctionalExplained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();  // add parts to the collection.    
FluentIterable<Integer> partsStartingA = 
    FluentIterable.from(parts).filter(new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final String input) {
            return input.startsWith("a");
        }
    }).transform(new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(final String input) {
            return input.length();
        }
    });
```

Seems to be an extensive library for Java. Certainly not as succinct as LINQ but looks interesting.

Answer (score 7):

https://code.google.com/p/joquery/

Supports different possibilities,

Given collection,

```
Collection<Dto> testList = new ArrayList<>();
```

of type,

```
class Dto
{
    private int id;
    private String text;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public int getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Filter**

***Java 7***

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter(testList)
    .where()
    .property("id").eq().value(1);
Collection<Dto> filtered = query.list();
```

***Java 8***

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter(testList)
    .where()
    .property(Dto::getId)
    .eq().value(1);
Collection<Dto> filtered = query.list();
```

Also,

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter()
        .from(testList)
        .where()
        .property(Dto::getId).between().value(1).value(2)
        .and()
        .property(Dto::grtText).in().value(new string[]{"a","b"});
```

**Sorting** (also available for the Java 7)

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter(testList)
        .orderBy()
        .property(Dto::getId)
        .property(Dto::getName)
    Collection<Dto> sorted = query.list();
```

**Grouping** (also available for the Java 7)

```
GroupQuery<Integer,Dto> query = CQ.<Dto,Dto>query(testList)
        .group()
        .groupBy(Dto::getId)
    Collection<Grouping<Integer,Dto>> grouped = query.list();
```

**Joins** (also available for the Java 7)

Given,

```
class LeftDto
{
    private int id;
    private String text;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public int getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

class RightDto
{
    private int id;
    private int leftId;
    private String text;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public int getLeftId()
        {
            return leftId;
        }

    public int getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

class JoinedDto
{
    private int leftId;
    private int rightId;
    private String text;

    public JoinedDto(int leftId,int rightId,String text)
    {
        this.leftId = leftId;
        this.rightId = rightId;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getLeftId()
    {
        return leftId;
    }

    public int getRightId()
        {
            return rightId;
        }

    public int getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

Collection<LeftDto> leftList = new ArrayList<>();

Collection<RightDto> rightList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Can be Joined like,

```
Collection<JoinedDto> results = CQ.<LeftDto, LeftDto>query().from(leftList)
                .<RightDto, JoinedDto>innerJoin(CQ.<RightDto, RightDto>query().from(rightList))
                .on(LeftFyo::getId, RightDto::getLeftId)
                .transformDirect(selection ->  new JoinedDto(selection.getLeft().getText()
                                                     , selection.getLeft().getId()
                                                     , selection.getRight().getId())
                                 )
                .list();
```

**Expressions**

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter()
    .from(testList)
    .where()
    .exec(s -> s.getId() + 1).eq().value(2);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try out my library [CollectionsQuery](https://bitbucket.org/mart_bogdan/collectionsquery/). It allows to run LINQ like queries over collections of objects. 
You have to pass predicate, just like in LINQ. If you are using java6/7 than you have to use old syntax with Interfaces:

```
List<String> names = Queryable.from(people)
                                    .filter(new Predicate<Person>() {
                                                public boolean filter(Person p) {
                                                    return p.age>20;
                                                }
                                            })
                                    .map   (new Converter<Person,String>() {
                                                public Integer convert(Person p) {
                                                    return p.name;
                                                }
                                            })
                                    .toList();
```

You can also use it in Java8, or in old java with [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) and it's [gradle plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda), then you will have new fancy syntax:

```
List<String> names = Queryable.from(people)
                                    .filter(p->p.age>20)
                                    .map   (p->p.name)
                                    .toList();
```

If you need to run DB queryes, than you can look on JINQ, as mentioned above, but it can't be back-ported by RetroLambda, doe to use of serialized lambdas.

Comment: Nice. Like https://leanpub.com/whatsnewinjava8/read#leanpub-auto-mapfilterreduce

Answer (score 4):

Just to add another alternative: Java 6 does have a solution for type-safe database queries using the [javax.persistence.criteria](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html) package.

Though i must say that this is not really LINQ, because with LINQ you can query any IEnumerable.

Comment: Yup it's a JPA API. Far from LINQ, but better than nothing. And one can say it's based loosely on Hibernate Criteria API. See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html

Answer (score 4):

There's a very good library that you can use for this.

Located here: https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light

Lambdas won't be available until Java 8 though, so using it is a bit different and doesn't feel as natural.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the Linq that everyone is talking about here is just LinqToObjects. Which I believe only offers functionality that can already be accomplished today in Java, but with really ugly syntax.

What I see as the real power of Linq in .Net is that lambda expressions can be used in a context requiring either a Delegate or an Expression and will then be compiled into the appropriate form. This is what allows things like LinqToSql (or anything other than LinqToObjects) to work, and allows them to have a syntax identical to LinqToObjects.

It looks like all of the projects referred to above are only offering the capabilities of LinqToObjects. Which makes me thing that LinqToSql-type functionality is not on the horizon for Java.

Answer (score 4):

For basic functional collections, Java 8 has it built in, most of the major non-Java JVM languages have it built in (Scala, Clojure, etc), and you can get add on libs for earlier Java versions.

For full language integrated access to a SQL database, Scala (runs on the JVM) has [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)

Answer (score 3):

For LINQ (LINQ to Objects), Java 8 will have something equivalent, see [Project Lambda](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/).

It has Enumerable's [LINQ to Objects extensions](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs) like [stuffs](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Iterable.java). But for more complicated LINQ things like [Expression](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq.Expressions/Expression.cs) and ExpressionTree (these are needed for LINQ to SQL and other LINQ providers if they want provide something optimized and real), there is not any equivalent yet but maybe we will see that in future :)

But I don't think there will be anything like declaratives queries on Java in future.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [tiny-q](https://code.google.com/p/tiny-q/). (Note that you currently can't download it.)

Here's an example adapted the above link:

> First we need a collection of some data, let's say a set of strings

```
String[] strings = { "bla", "mla", "bura", "bala", "mura", "buma" };
```

> Now we want to select only the strings which start with "b":

```
Query<String> stringsStartingWithB = new Query<String>(strings).where(
    new Query.Func<String, Boolean>(){
        public Boolean run(String in) {
            return in.startsWith("b");
        }
    }
);
```

> No actual data moved copied or anything like that, it will get processed as soon as you start iterating:

```
for(String string : stringsStartingWithB ) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in java. By using the other API you will get this feature.
Like suppose we have a animal Object containing name and id. We have list object having animal objects. Now if we want to get the all the animal name which contains 'o' from list object. we can write the following query

**`from(animals).where("getName", contains("o")).all();`**

Above Query statement will list of the animals which contains 'o' alphabet in their name.
More information please go through following blog.
http://javaworldwide.blogspot.in/2012/09/linq-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

JaQu is the LINQ equivalent for Java. Although it was developed for the H2 database, it should work for any database since it uses JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you're hoping for, but if some part of you code need heavy work on collections (searching, sorting, filtering, transformations, analysis) you may take in consideration to write some classes in [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) or [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29).

Because of their functional nature, working with collections is what they're best at. I don't have much experience with Scala, but with Clojure you'd probably find a more powerful Linq at your fingertips and once compiled, the classes you'd produce would integrate seamlessy with the rest of the code base.

Comment: Groovy or jRuby would also be viable candidates, since they all have a much more functional nature.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous user mentioned another one, [Diting](http://code.google.com/p/diting/):

> Diting is a class library provides query capabilities on collections through chainable methods and anonymous interface like Linq in .NET. Unlike most of other collection library those are using static methods need iterate whole collection, Diting provides a core Enumerable class whitch contains deffered chainable methods to implement query on collection or array.
>
> Supported Methods: any, cast, contact, contains, count, distinct, elementAt, except, first, firstOrDefault, groupBy, interset, join, last, lastOrDefault, ofType, orderBy, orderByDescending, reverse, select, selectMany, single, singleOrDefault, skip, skipWhile, take, takeWhile, toArray, toArrayList, union, where

Answer (score 1):

Scala.Now i star read it , and found it like linq but more simple and more unreadable.
but scala can run at linux,yes? csharp need mono.

Comment: Scala needs a Java runtime to run: it won't necessarily work on a bare Linux install either depending on what components you install.

Comment: @Rup there's **fully compliant** JRE for GNU/Linux, and Mono is **not a fully compliant** .NET implementation.

Comment: @Sarge That wasn't my point, but Mono runs LINQ well enough doesn't it? Besides, there's now Microsoft's own [.Net Core for Linux](http://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/).

Comment: (GNU/)Linux is not the only platform besides Windows, and JRE exists for a wide variety of platforms. Mono doesn't fully implement everything, for example there's no WPF.

Answer (score 0):

There was the programming language Pizza (a Java extension) and you should have a look to it. - It uses the concept of "fluent interfaces" to query data in a declarative manner and that is in principle identical to LINQ w/o query expressions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_programming_language). But alas it was not pursued, but it would have been one way to get something similar to LINQ into Java.

Comment: Sure it was pursued, just not under the name "Pizza".  The generics from Pizza got merged into GJ, which then became the Java 1.3 reference compiler (though generics were hidden behind a flag until 1.5).  In the meantime... the rest of the ideas, plus a few extra, became Scala.

Comment: Thanks for that info, of course Scala is a good point here. But these abilities where not integrated into the Java language. You could use the Scala language to implement the nice query code and use the resulting binary then from Java.

Comment: Also see ONGL at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/, which is in use and still being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a `"Linq to SQL"` equivalent for Java. but something close to it . [Query DSL](http://www.querydsl.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to LINQ for Java. 
But there is some of the external API which is looks like LINQ such as https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light, https://code.google.com/p/jaque/

Answer (score 0):

`HQL (Hibernate Query Language)` is very similar to `Linq` in `.Net`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library: https://code.google.com/p/qood/

Here are some reasons to use it:

1. lightweight: only 9 public interface/class to learn.
2. query like SQL: support group-by, order-by, left join,
   formula,...etc.
3. for big data: use File(QFS) instead of Heap Memory.
4. try to solve [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Functional Utils to convert C#'s 101 LINQ examples](https://github.com/mythz/java-linq-examples) that's compatible with Java 1.7 on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self plug: you could always use https://github.com/amoerie/jstreams

Works on Java 6 and up, a perfect fit for Android development.

It looks a lot like Scala operators, lodash, C# LINQ, etc.