# Getting a list of elements from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have a bean like below.

```
class Customer{
  private String code;
  private String name;
  private Integer value;
  //getters setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Then from a method I get a `List<Customer>` back. Now let's say I want to get a list of all member "name" from the List. Obviously I can traverse and build a `List<String>` of element "name" myself.

However, I was wondering if there is a short cut or more effiecient way to this technique that anyone knows . For instance, if I want to get a list of all keys in a Map object I get do map.keySet(). Something along that line is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: I think you're stuck looping, or if you're adventurous you can take a look at [quaere](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/quaere).  Take a look at [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq) for some related information.

Comment: I think you're not looking for a more efficient way, but perhaps for a more efficient way. The default for-loop is efficient enough, already.

Comment: Well not necessarily efficacy wise, but I was trying to get an idea of what others do for routine tasks  like this one. I learned about Guava and Lambdaj are some of the popular alternatives. So that's good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guava has [`Lists.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) that can transform a `List<F>` to a `List<T>`, using a provided [`Function<F,T>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) (or rather, `Function<? super F,? extends T>`).

From the documentation:

> ```
> public static <F,T>
>    List<T> transform(
>                List<F> fromList,
>                Function<? super F,? extends T> function
>            )
> ```
>
> Returns a list that applies `function` to each element of `fromList`. The returned list is a transformed view of `fromList`; changes to `fromList` will be reflected in the returned list and vice versa.
>
> The `function` is applied lazily, invoked when needed.

Similar live-view transforms are also provided as follows:

- [`Iterables.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) (`Iterable<F>` to `Iterable<T>`)
- [`Iterators.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#transform%28java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) (`Iterator<F>` to `Iterator<T>`)
- [`Collections2.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) (`Collection<F>` to `Collection<T>`)
- [`Maps.transformValues`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) (`Map<K,V1>` to `Map<K,V2>`)

Comment: Cool, good to see a link to a library that does essentially what I was suggesting in my post.

Comment: @Mark: the big difference is that Guava's implementation applies the function on-demand. Sort of "lazy transform", where as yours is eager.

Comment: Ah, I was curious as to why they were specifically using iterable.  That explains the reasoning.  I like it even more now (assuming there's a factory method in Guava to create a collection from an iterable?)

Comment: @Mark: I looked around and found `Collections2.transform`. But yes, there's `Iterables.addAll` from `Iterable` to `Collection`.

Comment: @Mark Peters Yeah, Guava can create any type of `Collection` from an `Iterable` with a factory method from a class like `Lists` or the `copyOf(Iterable)` factory method on all the immutable collection classes.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're looking for the Java equivalent of Perl's [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) function.  This kind of thing might be added to the collections library once (if) Java receives closures.  Until then, I think this is the best you can do:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(customers.size());
for ( Customer c : customers ) {
    list.add(c.getName());
}
```

You could also write a `map` function that uses a simple interface to provide the mapping function.  Something like this:

```
public interface Transform<I, O> {
    O transform(I in);
}
public <I, O> List<O> map(Collection<I> coll, Transform<? super I, ? extends O> xfrm) {
    List<O> list = new ArrayList<O>(coll.size());
    for ( I in : coll ) {
        list.add(xfrm.transform(in));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: "Perl's" map function? Hehe!  Don't you mean Java's equivalent of Perl's equivalent of Lisp's map function.

Answer (score 4):

could use something like this:
http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Answer (score 3):

I think this is something that you would have to code yourself, in a loop.

Comment: Using LambdaJ you just need to write the converter Customer->String

Comment: Or better yet ;-) guava's Lists.transform http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Function)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)'s [Converter](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/apidocs/ch/lambdaj/function/convert/Converter.html) interface and have the following line:

```
List<String> customerNames = convert(customerList, new Converter<Customer,String>() {
  public String convert(Customer customer) {
    return customer.getName();
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if it works with jdk 1.5 or is it Java 6 up only?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop, but the function you're looking for is called `map` in functional languages. It's possible to implement `map` in Java, although it tends to be fairly inelegant; here's the version I implemented ages ago in my "stuff Java should have but for some reason doesn't" library:

```
public interface MapFunction<T, U> {
    public U map(T source);
}

public static <T, U> U[] map(T[] objects, MapFunction<T, U> f) {
    if(objects.length == 0) {throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't map onto an empty array");}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") U[] rtn = (U[])Array.newInstance(f.map(objects[0]).getClass(), objects.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        rtn[i] = f.map(objects[i]);
    return rtn;
}
```

Using that, you could do:

```
List<Customer> list = yourFunction();
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(map(list.toArray(new Customer[0]), new MapFunction<Customer, String>() {
    public String map(Customer c) {
        return c.getName();
    }
}));
```

You could naturally change map to take collections instead of arrays, which would eliminate the need for `Arrays.asList` and `List.toArray`

Answer (score 2):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use a [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) along with [Iterables.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), [Collections2.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) or [Lists.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) to create an `Iterable`, `Collection` or `List` respectively.

```
Iterable<String> names = Iterables.transform(customers, 
    new Function<Customer, String>() {
      public String apply(Customer from) {
        return from.getName();
      }
    });
```

The returned `Iterable` is lazy and applies the function to the underlying list as you iterate through it. For a `List<String>` containing the names, you could use:

```
List<String> names = Lists.transform(...);
```

or

```
ImmutableList<String> names = ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.transform(...));
```

Of course, writing out the anonymous inner class `Function` implementation each time you want to do this is ugly and verbose, so you may want to make the `Function` a constant available from the `Customer` class, called `Customer.NAME` for instance.

Then the transformation looks much nicer (with static imports especially):

```
for (String name : transform(customers, Customer.NAME)) { ... }
```

I also wrote about using interfaces for particular properties of objects (such as `name` here) to help with consolidating such functions on my blog [here](http://blog.cgdecker.com/2010/06/property-interfaces-and-guava.html).

Comment: Okay both you and polygene sort of gave similar answers. If I could accept two answers as correct then I would have accepted yours too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> *.... is there  a short cut or more efficient way*

So, are you looking for a more efficient way to do this:

```
 List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
 for( Customer customer : yourCustomerList ) {
     names.add( customer.getName() );
 }
```

?!!!!

Or just a ***different*** way?

All the previous answer are not really more efficient in terms of runtime nor coding. They are however more flexible without a doubt.

Another alternative would be to  include <strike>Scala</strike> Groovy in your Java code and use this:

<strike>`list.map( _.name )`</strike>

```
list.collect { it.name }
```

If compiled, Groovy classes may be used from Java, or you can plug in them as an script.

Here's a sample for the given `Customer` class using Groovy as script.

```
    List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList( new Customer[]{
       new Customer("A","123",1),
       new Customer("B","456",2),
       new Customer("C","789",3),
       new Customer("D","012",4)
    });

    setVariable(customers, "list");
    evaluate("names = list.collect { it.name } ");
    List<String> names = (List<String>) getVariable("names");
    System.out.println("names = " + names);
```

Output:

```
names = [A, B, C, D]
```

<sub>note: I extracted method for readability, but you can see them below</sub>

But, again that's just different, not really  more efficient than the regular for loop.

Here's the [complete source code](http://pastebin.com/X8km9QCq). To run it you just need Java1.6 and Groovy in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard about Groovy but have not messed with it yet. This looks neat.