# Neat way of doing stuff with a List (and such) in Java

Tags: java

In C# you can do some operations on a list, like this:

```
return myList.Average(p => p.getValue());
```

This returns the average of all values. Is there something similar in Java? (That would save me the calculation of a sum and then division by the number of elements?)

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdaj provides much functionality like this:

```
Double totalAge = sumFrom(persons).getAge();
//Divide by size to get Average
```

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

Answer (score 4):

No but you could use [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html) and [transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html) to achieve the same. Here is [an example](http://codemunchies.com/2009/11/functional-java-filtering-and-ordering-with-google-collections-part-3/)

You can use [Lists.transform(...)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html) as well. It will apply the function to the same elements (no copies are created).

Comment: it would take quite a hack to do this via function and transform (transform is meant to transform n values of one type into n values of another, not collect a common value). How about a code example?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of collection you are creating.  I don't think the native java Array types support any functionality like this.  However there are other collections that can do these sorts of things, for example Apache Commons Math has a number of structures to do just this sort of thing.  Guava is another package with a lot of great Array methods built in.

Another option one could easily implement would be to extend the collection your using.  For example:

```
public class ArrayListExtension extends ArrayList{

  public ArrayListExtension(){}

  public Double average()
  {
     Double sum = 0;
     Iterator<Double> iterator = this.iterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext()){
       sum += iterator.next();
     }
     return sum/this.size();
  }
}
```

Note:  There are no sanity checks built into this.  In a real-world implementation you'd want to do some try-catch to make sure that the values are actual numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't use `float` esp when your values are `double`.

Comment: Good point @Peter Lawrey.  Edited the response to return a Double instead.

Comment: I wouldn't use `Double` either, unless you want to allow a `null` value. `double` is much more efficent and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get the average of some numbers.  Unless you do this lot, there isn't much saving.

```
public static double average(Collection<Number> coll) {
   double total = 0;
   for(Number n: coll) total += n.doubleValue();
   return total/coll.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safe version of Peter Lawrey's answer, using `BigDecimal`:

```
public static double safeAverage(final Collection<? extends Number> coll){
    BigDecimal dec = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for(final Number n : coll){
        dec = dec.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(n.doubleValue()));
    }
    return dec.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(coll.size())).doubleValue();
}
```

(Not quite safe, however, as `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` also extend `Number`. Safe if used with any of the `Number` implementations in `java.lang`)