# Is there a Java equivalent for LINQ?

Tags: java, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq)

There are numerous questions asking whether there is a Java equivalent for LINQ. But most of them are incorrectly specifying that there is nothing.

Comment: `most of them are incorrectly specifying that there is nothing` - then why are you asking the question if you are so sure they are "incorrectly specifying that there is nothing"?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? First you ask a question where you state that answers to other similar questions are incorrect and then you answer yourself by linking to a project. Is it something you are involved in and want to market or what?

Comment: I come from a .NET background and I'm using this library. When researching for something like this all I saw was "No there is nothing". So it's for others who have to use Java for a project.

Comment: @Fredrik: this is [acceptable and even encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @GregKopff Even if there are other questions that ask the same thing? Couldn't he just have answered one of that questions saying that the other answers were wrong?

Comment: @Pable but these are already answered and accepted

Comment: @Pablo: yes, that part is true - I agree.

Comment: @GregKopff I know and I didn't say it wasn't. I was just wondering about the idea behind rejecting answers to similar questions as incorrect and then add this instead of answering the other questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This library provides a full LINQ API: https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light

It does so with functional-style constructs and it also uses deferred execution.

```
// select names starting with j, using LINQ-style statements
new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).distinct().all(println());
```

Comment: No lambdas, no cigar.  The ability to take _expressions_, and break them down to their components, and translate those into a SQL expression for complex hierarchical queries is still missing completely.

Comment: @DaveMorganTexas LINQ-to-SQL != LINQ.

Comment: @EvanPlaice - the appropriate terminology would be `query expression`, not `SQL expression`. If Dave were able to make that replacement, his comment would become more universally applicable, rather than only in the realm of SQL

Comment: As pointed out in comments in [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq), changes to C# and the .Net framework were required -- Lambdas, extension methods -- and only **then** were they able to create the libraries of methods that are the LINQ-providers.  Until they make the deep changes in Java, all "LINQ APIs" are going to be shallow cheap imitations, bolt-on "decorators" that in the end will still require tons of code to properly "work around" the lack of deep integration achieved in LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

Another one that I've tried myself is jaque: http://code.google.com/p/jaque/

Comment: Is this up-to-date? It says it uses Java 7 closures. They are no closures in JDK 7 though...

Comment: Yeah that's weird. But it has the usual methods `where`, `select`, etc.