# How to query a list of a class in java

Tags: java, linq, list

I have class named class1 with two members, member1 and member2. I want to query on an ArrayList of class1 based on member1. We could do this in C# very easy using linq. and I found out that in java we can use libraries like what that has proposed in:

[Is there a Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879761/is-there-a-java-equivalent-for-linq)

However I don't have the time to learn this library, it has a loooot of jar files in its library and I don't know which one I should import to use the functionality I need. It seems it takes time. Can someone give me a programming hint, an equivalent program that can be replaced with that query. It seems I cannot think out of the box of linq. Is there any way to do that query without using these kinds of libraries?

Comment: What you're looking for is part of Java 8.  But if you have Java 7 or below, the best way is just to write the conditions yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ can do a lot of things and there is no single alternative for it. Java has no LINQ library, it's a .NET thing. You can do a lot of common LINQ operations in Java 8 though with streams and functional programming, such as your example:

```
Class1[] arr = ...
List<Class1> filteredList = stream(arr).filter(e -> e.member1 == val).collect(toList());
```

This generates a list of elements where `member1` equals `val`.

For more examples, I'll refer to this package: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

If Java 8 is not available, then you have to resort to using simple for loops (or downloading a library to do this for you).

Comment: java.util.stream is not in my system libraries, should I download it from somewhere and add it? sorry I couldn't find its download link.

Comment: Which version of Java do you have?  This stuff is Java 8.

Comment: Ok, I will check that. I have recently installed eclipse, and this is my first program in java. I'm not sure. Thank you, this seems very similar to linq.

Comment: I am using this stream, but I don't need to import java.util.stream.* in my project, when I hover over the stream() function, it shows java.util.collection.stream(), I want to make sure that I am using it correctly. because my program seems to take for ever to be completed.