# Java equivalent of database IN

Tags: java, keyword, list-literal

I have been wondering for sometime why java doesn't have any keyword like "IN" that is used in SQL/PL-SQL. It's quite a useful keyword that helps to compare value to several other values at once instead of writing ugly code with || or lengthy if-else! Any propositions of this kind in JSRs?

PS: I am not looking for a workaround, but I wanted to know if there was any particular reason that this functionality doesn't exist in java or any proposals in near future

Comment: There's `Collection.contains()`. Doesn't that do what you want? Please post some example (pseudo-) code of what you'd like to see.

Comment: I think he means something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IN ('Foo','Bar');` - the key point being that you can concisely specify the list to compare against...

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1217228/938695

Comment: This is Java, not Groovy :D, in groovy there is a operator "in" :D

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any firm proposals to add this to Java. There is a [blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2007/02/java-7-list-and-map-literals_6278.html) (and [another](http://multiple-hats.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/jdk7-closures-dynamic-typing-support-in.html)) discussing the possibility adding of list literals, which would get you most of the way there using `contains()` - this seems to have been discussed for Java 7 but not adopted.

**Update:** Looks like list literals have been deferred until Java 8 - see [this article](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/), for example.

Rather than using `contains()` and direct Array literals or Lists, you could define a helper using varargs:

```
boolean in(Object o, Object... vals)
{
    return Arrays.asList(vals).contains(o);
}
```

So that you could do:

```
if (in(x, "a", "b", "c"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

But that's still a bit ugly and verbose compared to the SQL `IN` or the Python:

```
if x in ['a','b','c']:
    print "yes"
```

Comment: This is the workaround, the best one at that. I necessitates creating an Arraylist everytime I need a comparision, which doesn't give the same ease as a native keyword!

Comment: Yes; the problem is not so much the lack of the `in` keyword, but the fact that array literals are verbose, and there are no List literals in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Collection` has the methods `contains` and `containsAll` which might get the job done, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

But Java can easily be connected to a database(JDBC). You do have a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) construct though that is helpful and similar to `IN`:

```
for (Suit suit : suits)
    for (Rank rank : ranks)
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can create a collection and use the method [`boolean contains(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

In collections

[Collection.contains(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

and In String you have [String.contains(CharSequence c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0):

I think so,

that realy is a missing Feature.

For example:

```
String[] list = new String[]{"Tim","Tammy","Tod"};
if("Ted" in list){
    System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

would be realy easy to understand.

Comment: i guess most of the time its not clear that the operator .equals() or  == or .compareTo() should be used to compare "Tim" and "Ted" for example.

Comment: Well, if it is an intelligent comparator, it will do string comparision for string values and non-string comparision for non-string values!

Comment: Case sensitive? Charset sensitive? Trimed? Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like,

```
List<String> values = ArrayLists.create("AVALUE", "BVALUE");

if (values.contains(yourValue))
// Do whatever
```

Comment: This is kind of a workaround, isn't it. Creating an arraylist everytime I need a comparision looks like a compromise!