# best way or similar lambda expression or linq on android (eclipse)

Tags: java, android, linq, lambda

for example if i have

```
ArrayList<Product> productlist = new ArrayList<Product> ();
```

how do you get all the products which `product.code` equals to 1 and 2?

is there a library which can i use?

in c# i could use

```
productlist.where(product=> product.code.contains(arraywithproductcode)).ToList();
```

or other way was using

```
var newlist=(from p in productlist join a in arraywithproduct on a.product equals a select p);
```

how can i get it in java for android?

Comment: Check out the TotallyLazy library: http://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lambda expressions in Android (or Java) yet.

You might want to see these options (haven't tested them in Android though):

- Quaere: http://quaere.codehaus.org
- JaQu: http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html
- Linq4j: https://github.com/julianhyde/linq4j
- Slick: http://slick.typesafe.com/

Also, see [this DZone link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/linq-and-java) and [this one](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/07/01/linq-and-java/). A stackoverflow post [mentions this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq).

### **Update**:

Lambda expression are now available in Java SE 8
For more information visit:

[Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Lambdas are coming to Java next year, in version 8.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this introductory article [Java 8 Stream on Android — Medium](https://medium.com/@nicopasso/java-8-stream-on-android-c629e4237d5f#.g3a52y5c8), there are two gems that seem to play really nicely together to provide the kind of LINQ-like experience you're asking for.

These are called [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) and [Stream](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API).

Added bonus, they don't need Java 8, so using them is compatible with old versions of Android.

Your C# code:

```
productlist
.where(product=> product.code.contains(arraywithproductcode))
.ToList();
```

Would turn to something like this:

```
productlist
.filter(product -> product.code.contains(arraywithproductcode))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With the usual remark: "Do you really need to turn it into a list at the end? Perhaps the lazily-evaluated stream is what you actually want."

For other examples, use [aNNiMON/Android-Java-8-Stream-Example: Demo app of using Java 8 features with Retrolambda and Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Android-Java-8-Stream-Example)

We use that here with Android Studio, but I would be surprised if it did not work with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you could either create a new list, iterate over the old one and add the ones matching your criteria to your new list.

If you want to avoid that and can live with the limitations of Guavas [`Collections2.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method, you can do this:

```
Collection<Product> filtered = Collections2.filter(productlist, new Predicate<Product>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Product p) {
        return p.code == 1 || p.code == 2;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this Java library: https://code.google.com/p/qood/

It handles data without any getter/setters, so it's more flexible than LINQ.

in your Product case, it might looks like:

```
final String[] productCodeArray = { ... };
final QModel products = ...; //QModel {PROD_CODE, PROD_FIELD1, PROD_FIELD2, ...}
final QModel filtered = products.query()
  .where(QNew.<String>whereIn("PROD_CODE").values(productCodeArray))
  .result().debug(-1);
```