# java quivalent of linq + lambda expression

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Say in C# I have the following code:

```
int i = 1;
ListOfInts.Where(li=>li > i).ToList();
```

I am wondering when I am using Hibernate, are there any possible way of doing similar stuff from above, instead of using the HQL?

Comment: this looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1217228/217324

Comment: @NathanHughes Well, there's Java 8... On top of that, Hibernate may have its own little tricks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: i think answers to the linked question cover that. there seem to be multiple ways to do something like linq with Hibernate. granted the selected answer is not terribly helpful.