# OrderByDecending(LINQ) equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c#, linq

Hi I am a c# developer getting into Java. The question is simple:

How can i write the below c# code into Java and still get it to work:

```
myCoffeeList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name?.ToLower()?.Trim() == sender.Text.ToLower()?.Trim()));
```

My `sender.Text` is basically a textbox.Text with a value like `Cappuccino`.

### What does the above code do?

Well I have a collection of coffee and I want that the name of the coffee that exactly matches the sender.text should be on top and the rest can be of the order returned from the server.

### I've checked out the below:

1. [list.streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to use something like a LINQ
2. [Anotation type OrderBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) but it's related to databases

Comment: The question context seems similar like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq. You can found something useful things there.

Comment: You can use a custom `Comparable`, here is a good place to start learning about them https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No the question is quite different from that, reason being, I don't want to use LINQ. I just want to get an idea on how can I achieve what the above codeline does in Java

Comment: @Titus thanks I was looking at the `Comparable`, can you please help me out with a sample?\

Comment: coffee.sort((a, b) -> a.equals(top) ? -1 : 0); look down

Comment: GGO, I think the C# tag should stay, as there are a few recent/relatively advanced C# mechanisms at work here and I wouldn't expect a core java guru with passing knowledge of C# to reasonably know what all these things are..

Comment: @CaiusJard good suggest

Comment: @iam.Carrot unless I misunderstand the way `entity?.method` works, I don't think it's required on .ToLower() - ToLower() will never return null, and cannot be called on a null, so stopping at x.Name? would be fine => if name is null the runtime will cease trying to call further methods and evaluate the expression as null

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah thanks for that man. It just got as a habit to put that `?` maybe I over used it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Coffee> sorted = lst.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(sender.trim())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I can't use your answer as it's using a string while My object is of type Coffee and the object of coffee has a peroperty/field named Name of type string

Comment: Ok. I just given an idea. Anyway just consider the string as a instance of Coffee object. And get the coffee name by getter method.

Comment: can you please share a sample where in we take a coffee object and match the name to the string?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Considering sender as String.

Comment: You can use `...equalsIgnoreCase(...)` to replace those `...toLowerCase()` calls.

Comment: You are welcome. I've edited as per the suggestion given by Titus.

Comment: need null checking to perfectly convert into java code

Answer (score -1):

Use Comparable and the sort method:

```
List<String> coffee = new ArrayList<>();
coffee.add("C");
coffee.add("A");
coffee.add("B");
coffee.add("D");

String top = "D";
coffee.sort((a, b) -> a.equals(top) ? -1 : 0);
coffee.forEach(System.out::println);
```

EDIT: for natural order use:

```
coffee.sort((a, b) -> a.equals(top) ? -1 : a.compareTo(b));
```