# Java sort key-value collection

Tags: java, sorting

I normally use C# and am not very familiar with Java API, but here is what I want to do:

I have two arrays:

```
String[] names = concertNames.toArray(new String[concertNames.size()]);
Double[] rates = concertRates.toArray(new Double[concertRates.size()]);
```

Each element from `names` corresponds to elements from `rates`, i.e. `names[i]` has a rate of `rates[i]`.

I would like to get the names of N top-rated concerts. In C# I would use LINQ, and here, I'm not sure.

**Edit:** Off-topic? Are you people serious? I know how to sort an array, I just don't want to write 50 lines of horrible, rudimentary code in order to do a trivial thing.

Comment: Please write at least 2 lines of code!!!!.. How it's possible this question has several upvotes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq)

Comment: Why would you use parallel arrays instead of an array of objects holding `name` and `rate` for each concert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neatest way I can think of is to stream the indexes, sort them by their rates and then map them to their names:

```
String[] topNames = 
    IntStream.range(0, rates.length)
             .boxed()
             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> -1 * rates[i]))
             .limit(N)
             .map(i -> names[i])
             .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: OP wants *"names of N top-rated concerts"*, so for `limit()` to retain top-rated concerts, the sort needs to be descending, e.g. `.sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> rates[i]).reversed())`.

Comment: @Andreas good catch, thanks. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> rates[i]).reversed())` would be better.

Comment: Is it for developer readability that you use `-1 * rates[i]` instead of `-rates[i]`?

Comment: @Aominè that was my first instinct too, but it messes up the type inference of `i`. You could use `(Integer i) -> ...` instead if `i -> ...`, of course, but that's a bit clunky, IMHO.

Comment: @Andreas yup, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Considering there is a relationship between an element in `names` and an element in `rates` I'd suggest you create a class to encapsulate these two fields, therefore, making it both easier to sort the objects based on the rate and also maintaining related data.

Another option would be to create a `Map<String, Double>` where each name is mapped to its corresponding rate.

if you decide to proceed with the first suggestion of creating your own class to encapsulate the two said fields you can accomplish the task like this:

```
NameOfClass[] topRated = myList.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(NameOfClass::getRate).reversed())
                .limit(10) // Top N
                .toArray(NameOfClass[]::new);
```

if you decide to proceed with the suggested Map approach, something like this would suffice:

```
Map<String, Double> resultSet = myMap.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .limit(10) // Top N
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                         (oldValue, newValue) -> ... , LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: http://www.jinq.org. inq makes LINQ-style queries are available for Java