# Is it possible that JsonPath work with Collection of Java objects?

Tags: java, json, collections, jsonpath

I want to filter collection of Java DTO Objects using `JsonPath` library.
I have `List<AuthorGetDto>` with some objects and I want to do something like this:

```
List<AuthorGetDto> authors = authorService.getAllAuthors();
List<AthorGetDto> filtered = JsonPath.read(authors, "$.[?(@.authorId=='985')]");
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or I must firstly parse this objects to String than filter them using JsonPath, and after that convert them to `List<AuthorGetDto>`?

Comment: Post a [mcve], including the relevant definitions of `AuthorGetDto`, `authorService` and `JsonPath`.

Comment: No, JsonPath is for querying json. Java objects are not json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq